# Oracle - Alter unique index by adding or removing columns

Tags: oracle, indexing

I have a unique index

```
create unique index TestDB.UniqueIndex_lookup_uk on TestDB.message_Rule(format_id,direction,subtype,state);
```

How can i alter this unique index by adding or removing columns ?

Edit : Is there any way to do that without dropping and recreating the `index` ?

Comment: `drop index` then create a new one

Answer (score 0):

Found another discussion at this link and it says CREATE OR REPLACE can be used for some object types but not for indexes.
https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/is-create-or-replace-index-supported-6125#comment_323462162492613588246641378589898615657